Why does Microsoft Access 365 close randomly and relaunches?
I am running Microsoft Access 365 [Click To Run - Microsoft® Access® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2410 Build 16.0.18129.20100) 64-bit].
I notice that when I try to open forms or switch from Design view to Normal View; run queries; execute VBA code or perform other tasks, that Access randomly just closes and relaunches (in the iOS world would call it a respring). There are no messages and no obvious errors.
How could I figure out what is causing these errors? I am at a loss for what could be happening and cannot find any pattern.
I have tried to compact and repair the database.
This happens with multiple MS Access databases.

You'll need to check the event viewer. Access doesn't do this just because, it's not a normal or common thing.


Check that your using the same version of Access used to make the DB's and queries. 2. Try reinstalling the Access runtime: https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/download-and-install-microsoft-365-access-runtime-185c5a32-8ba9-491e-ac76-91cbe3ea09c9  3. Try software running on PC, e.g., Access standalone, https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/p/access/CFQ7TTC0PD0B


@music2myear how do I access that

@psycoperl - Access what exactly?

@Ramhound The Event Viewer

Through Control Panel? Event Viewer hasn’t changed in decades

@Ramhound - In 20+ years I have never had to use Event Viewer.

In Event Viewer what exactly am I looking for? This is all new to me. Thank you in advance for your help and guidance. @music2myear

Event Viewer is where Windows, and many applications running on it, do all their logging. First thing to do is look in the Windows and Applications sections of Event Viewer for events that happen around the time Access crashes. You can also look online to see what "EventID" Access uses to record its own issues, which will allow you to filter the messages. In general, if it is an actual application crash, you'll see events noting what part of the application the crash happened in.
